# Installing Lubuntu 18.04 on old x86 tablet

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu

I have been trying to install Lubuntu 18.04 in an old x86 tablet to use as a notetaking device (HP Slate 2), so far the only distro that worked was the Lubuntu alternate install for the 14.04 LTS version, the desktop versions using the GUI installer give an initramfs error:

`(initramfs) unable to find a medium containing a live file system`

The other problem is when using the alternate installs past version 15.10 the usb keyboard does not work. Any solutions that could help me? Thank you!

EDIT: All the bootable usb were made in Rufus in Windows although I've tried the startup disk creator on Ubuntu 20.04 with no sucess

---

Well I found out something, the reason why the installers failed was because of the linux kernel version, i tried to update from version 14.04 to 16.04 via USB livecd and, as soon as the linux kernel version 4 is installed all of the USB ports on the tablet stop working so this might be the reason why I can't install ever more recent versions of linux distros, anyone can recommend a fix to this?

---

FINAL EDIT: [And maybe this can be closed as anwsered] I noticed using wibu installer for xubuntu 18.04 that the sdcard was recognized and mounted. Following the Antix distro recommendition in the answers, using Rufus in my desktop i created two bootable media, one usb pendrive as this device does not boot from the sdcard and the sdcard, this resulted in an smooth installation of the OS. Hope this might help someone with a similar problem to mine!

Comment: All Ubuntu flavors with a 32-bit version are out of support now. Standard Ubuntu 18.04 is still supported until 2023 but obviously too much for such hardware. There aren't many alternatives going forward but among them Debian and AntiX are to be considered. Forget Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm going to check out the AntiX, I'm kinda new to this scene :)

Comment: FYI:  It reads to me like you've insufficient RAM in your device... The alternate installer was used for boxes that had 768MB or less of RAM, as there wasn't sufficient RAM in those boxes to run both the *live* ISO and run `ubiquity` (the installer) at the same time... The alternate ISO exists for Lubuntu 18.04 (but was never updated; they never were for any releasec via re-spin, thus it'll have 3+ years of updates to install now)

Comment: Are you aware that flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that is now EOL (*end-of-life*).  See https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/ https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/  with support ending April-2021.   Use `ubuntu-support-status` on your system to confirm the supported/unsupported packages & act accordingly (ie. how important is security to you, are you offline etc?)

Comment: Another thought - what CPU are using using?   Is it a old intel device with PAE issues? and you need to force the OS to *pretend* it has PAE despite the CPU saying it doesn't (the bug).   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE  a look and your CPU I wouldn't expect that issue (https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/55663/intel-atom-processor-z670-512k-cache-1-50-ghz.html) but a i686 cpu in 2011 means it was an old design...

Comment: Back to the fight, now I'm going to try your recommendations @guiverc I'll say something in a bit, suposedly this tablet has 2GB RAM, this is just for notetaking with the stylus so I'm not really concerned about safety!